Remove any observations containing only characters (or a zip code with no other numeric values)
I'm trying to create a flag for flawed addresses and my idea is to remove all observations that have no numeric value in them. I don't want zip codes, so first step would be to remove those) and then apply a second filter to remove anything without non-remaining numeric values.
In the following data frame, I would want to retain only the second row (containing a numeric address). The first row is only characters, and the third row, while containing numeric values, really only contains a five digit zipcode.
d = {'col1': ['San Diego County, California', '4150 Ute Dr, San Diego, California', 'Vista del Lago, Perris, California, 92570'], 'col2': ['prov_1', 'prov_2', 'prov_3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df



What about using a regex to match 1-4 digits, followed by optional spaces then letters?
out = df[df['col1'].str.contains(r'\d{1,4}\s*[a-zA-Z]+')]

Output:
                                 col1    col2
1  4150 Ute Dr, San Diego, California  prov_2

regex demo
Note that this should also work without specifying a limit on the digits as long as you have letters after the digits:
out = df['col1'].str.extract(r'(\d+\s*[a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)


Thanks! The only issue I'm seeing are edge cases where an address could be 5 or more digits. But I think the case in which there are letters after the digits should take care of that.
